# How to deploy create-react-app to gh-pages subfolder?

Tags: github-pages, create-react-app

I'm still learning web development and doing courses so, I have separate repos for each school I'm doing.
I have many small projects in each big repo which was no problem until I started using `create-react-app` as I can't deploy to `gh-pages` without it's deploy command wiping out the other project folders on `gh-pages`. Is it possible to deploy it into a subfolder within `gh-pages` somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gh-pages` has a `-e` or `--dest` option to specify which directory to push all the files to.

```
./node_modules/gh-pages/bin/gh-pages.js --help
```

> Usage: gh-pages [options]
>
> ```
> Options:
>
> -V, --version            output the version number
> -d, --dist <dist>        Base directory for all source files
> -s, --src <src>          Pattern used to select which files to publish (default: **/*)
> -b, --branch <branch>    Name of the branch you are pushing to (default: gh-pages)
> -e, --dest <dest>        Target directory within the destination branch (relative to the root) (default: .)
> -a, --add                Only add, and never remove existing files
> -x, --silent             Do not output the repository url
> -m, --message <message>  commit message (default: Updates)
> -g, --tag <tag>          add tag to commit
> -t, --dotfiles           Include dotfiles
> -r, --repo <repo>        URL of the repository you are pushing to
> -p, --depth <depth>      depth for clone (default: 1)
> -o, --remote <name>      The name of the remote (default: origin)
> -v, --remove <pattern>   Remove files that match the given pattern (ignored if used together with --add). (default: .)
> -n, --no-push            Commit only (with no push)
> -h, --help               output usage information
> ```

So, you can change you `package.json` to have the following deploy script.

```
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build -e project-directory-name",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Where in `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build -e project-directory-name",`,  you'll have to give a different name for each project

Comment: thank you, so much! this is exactly what I was looking for :) much appreciated!

Comment: You're most welcome @Jutzee :) . I tried to explain my thought process for solving this problem too. Hope you could understand that.

Comment: I see that you're new to Stackoverflow. Kudos on asking a good question to get started. You're doing well. Let us know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: If you're interested in contributing to open source projects, take a look at my side project [First Contributions](https://github.com/Roshanjossey/first-contributions/blob/master/README.md)